# Como proteger meu servidor Scrapyd de chamadas não autenticadas?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, web-crawler, scrapy

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte configuração no scrapy.cfg no Scrapyd.

```
[deploy]
url = http://example.com/api/scrapyd/
username = user
password = secret
project = projectX
```

Na documentação do Scrapyd ele cita as opções username e password, mas aparentemente eu continuo mandando as spiders rodarem mesmo sem autenticação.

A pergunta que fica é, como proteger meu servidor Scrapyd de chamadas indesejadas/não autenticadas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, essa configuração de username/password é uma configuração do cliente para uma [autenticação HTTP básica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), que o [scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd) atualmente não implementa.

Para você configurar isso no seu servidor, o caminho é deixar o scrapyd escutando somente conexões locais (127.0.0.1) e configurar um Nginx (ou outro proxy HTTP) com a autenticação HTTP na frente, repassando as requisições para o scrapyd.

Aqui tem uma configuração pronta pra usar num container [Docker](https://www.docker.com): https://github.com/mattes/scrapyd

Caso usar o Docker não seja uma opção, você pode se inspirar no [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mattes/scrapyd/blob/master/Dockerfile) e no [nginx.conf](https://github.com/mattes/scrapyd/blob/master/nginx.conf) providenciado no repositório pra fazer o processo manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode editar as configurações do scrapyd e colocar a seguinte configuração no arquivo ~/.scrapyd.conf:

```
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

Isso vai fazer o servidor apenas poder ser utilizado por processos sendo executados nele mesmo.

Caso você deseje proteger com senha, você também poderá usar o servidor apache como proxy e adicionar uma autenticação básica. Abaxio segue um exemplo de virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourserver
    DocumentRoot /var/www/service-status
    <Directory /var/www/service-status/>
        Require valid-user
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Protected"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/service-status/.htpasswd
    </Directory>
    <Location /api/>
        ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:40500/
        ProxyPassReverse  http://127.0.0.1:40500/        
    </Location>
    <Proxy *>
        Require valid-user
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Protected"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/service-status/.htpasswd
    </Proxy>    
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule ^/?api$         /api/ [QSA,L,R]
    RewriteRule ^/?jobs(.*)     /api/jobs$1 [QSA,L,R]
    RewriteRule ^/?logs(.*)     /api/logs$1 [QSA,L,R]
    RewriteRule ^/?items(.*)    /api/items$1 [QSA,L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

No exemplo acima, os comandos da API ficariam disponíveis em http://seudominio/api/comando.json

O arquivo .htpasswd precisará ser criado para que o virtualserver funcione.